# How use rotateY with javascript to animate flipcards?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

Hello everyone I want to flip cards 25degree and then -25degree again on pageload.
I have used rotateY how ever cards are rotating just once. Should i use settimeout function for the second style change?

Use Case: I want to show user that they can hover on them and see the behind therefore i am trying to move then +25 and -25 degree on page load

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(".flip-card").css({ 'transform':'rotateY(-25deg)'});
$(".flip-card").css({ 'transform':'rotateY(+25deg)'});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can find a demo https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGID52DZ542M

Comment: Yes, you need time out.

Comment: I have changed to this but still it doesnt come back to inital position
$(".flip-card").css({ 'transform':'rotateY(-25deg)'});
setTimeout(function(){ $(".flip-card").css({ 'transform':'rotateY(25deg)'}); }, 500);

Comment: or rotateY to zero?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery, but with JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
h1.classList.add("red");
window.setTimeout(() => h1.classList.remove("red"), 1111);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Foo</h1>
```